# Django Добавление комментариев

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django

Проблема заключается в том что если ввести комментарий и нажать на кнопку ДОБАВИТЬ несколько раз подряд быстро, то комментарий  добавится несколько раз.

Подскажите как сделать проверку для добавления комментариев что бы можно было добавлять раз в 30 сек допустим.

модель и форма простая

```
class Reviews(models.Model):

    name= models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя')
    text= models.TextField('Сообщение',max_length=500)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,verbose_name='Продукт',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,db_index=True,verbose_name='Добавлено')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}-{self.product}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Отзыв'
        verbose_name_plural='Отзывы'
        ordering = ['-data',]


class ReviewsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= PostRewiews
        fields= ('text',)



class BlogAddReview(View):

    def post(self,request,id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
            form=ReviewsForm(request.POST or None)
            if  form.is_valid():
                form=form.save(commit=False)
                form.name = request.user.username
                form.post=post
                form.save()
            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
        else:
            return redirect('login')
```

Comment: 1) можно поставить hidden поле с генерированным uuid и проверять, нет ли записи с таким же и не позволять добавлять

Comment: 2) data есть время создания записи, соответственно просто доставай последнюю в базе и проверяй, если время отличается от текущего на 30 сек, можно добавлять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кому интересно решил проблему с дублированием отзывов так. Добавил в модель поле  postId  = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4) и проверку  на соотношение с последним теkстом.С редиректами прошу подсказать

```
class BlogAddReview(View):

    def post(self,request,id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
            lastPost = PostRewiews.objects.first()
            form=ReviewsForm(request.POST or None)
            if  form.is_valid():
                form=form.save(commit=False)
                if lastPost:
                    if lastPost.postId == form.postId or post.postrewiews_set.first().text == form.text :
                        try:
                            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
                        except:
                            return redirect('blog')
                form.name = request.user.username
                form.post=post
                form.save()
            try:
                return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
            except:
                return redirect('blog') 
            return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю при первом клике "дизейблить" кнопку.

```
function disable_on_click() {
  var element = document.getElementById('the-button-id');
  element.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Comment: Вариант хороший, но не дает 100% гарантию. Если у человека отключен JS то не сработает. Если ошибка в коде - не сработает. Если программно тыкнуть - не сработает. Проверять лучше на сервере, проверка на клиенте для ленивых)

Answer (score 2):

Можно реализовать если поле text прошлого комментария равно полю текст нового комментария, то тогда не добавлять комментарий. последний объект можно взять из бд методом Reviews.object.last() и из него взять данные. Таким методом можно еще проверить поле name, не думаю что люди с одинаковым именем будут писать одинаковые комментарии. А если бы была привязка к User было бы вообще шикарно как по мне.

Answer (score 1):

Берешь последний комментарий из базы и проверяешь текущее время и время последнего комментария в базе, если они отличаются, значит можно добавлять комментарий. Дальше логику можешь сам поправить в `def checkDouble`. Код не проверял, могут быть ошибки, но логика такая.

```
class BlogAddReview(View):

    def post(self,request,id):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
            form=ReviewsForm(request.POST or None)
            if  form.is_valid() and checkDouble():
                form=form.save(commit=False)
                form.name = request.user.username
                form.post=post
                form.save()
            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
        else:
            return redirect('login')

    def checkDouble(self):
        import datetime
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        lastReviews = Reviews.objects.last()
        if now != lastReviews.data:
           return True
        else:
           return False
```

Comment: Лучше бы написал про `guid`. В текущем предложенном варианте дата время может отличаться на миллисекунду. а запросы не придут в одно и тоже время никогда. А значит не совпадут. А если еще и ожидают ответа, а сервер нагружен, то вообще можно через 5 сек снова тыкнуть. Оптимальный вариант через GUID, или проверять совпадения текущих данных с прошлыми, сохранив прошлый например в сессии иле кеше ко ключу сессии / id пользователя.

Comment: ну да, можно так, я выше писал, только указал, как uuid. Получается его надо в поле hidden добавлять, и при отправке формы проверять, нет ли в базе второй такой записи

Comment: при всех вариантах происходит  "ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение" и нет возможности проверить  UUID , думал дело в бд но на постгресс та же ошибка

Comment: тут уже надо тестить базу данных и настройки базы